# How to divide the data entered on the screen into zones(flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter, and I can't figure out how to properly zone the data that is displayed. On the screen I want to display a pie chart, a counter of free seals, and also data on the user (I still develop this part). But I do not understand how to do it. I will be grateful for your help !.
Here is my code(change):

```html
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;
import  'package:flutter_app_seals/model/setting/globalvar.dart' as global;
void main()=>runApp(AppS());

class Task{
  String task;
  int taskvalue;
  Color colors;
  Task({this.task,this.taskvalue,this.colors});
}



class AppS extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home:Home()
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  List<dynamic> data = [];
  Map<String, dynamic> statsIndia;
  List<charts.Series<Task, String>> _seriesPieData =
  List<charts.Series<Task, String>>();
  int a, b, c;

  Future<Null> getUserDetails() async {


    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.badCertificateCallback = ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true);

    final String url = global.urlVar +  '/PIE' + '?data_area=' + global.dataArea;
    final request = await client
        .getUrl(Uri.parse(url))
        .timeout(Duration(seconds: 5));

    HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();

    var responseBody = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();


    data = json.decode(responseBody);
    statsIndia = data[0];
    a = statsIndia["unseals"];
    b = statsIndia["seals"];
    c = statsIndia["free_seals"];
    print(a);
    get();
    setState(() {});
  }


  get() {
    var piedata = [
      new Task(task: "Seals", taskvalue: a, colors: Color(0xfffd2525)),
      new Task(task: "Unseals", taskvalue: b, colors: Color(0xffb5e09b))
    ];
    _seriesPieData.add(charts.Series(
      data: piedata,
      domainFn: (Task task, _) => task.task,
      measureFn: (Task task, _) => task.taskvalue,
      colorFn: (Task task, _) => charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(task.colors),
      labelAccessorFn: (Task row, _) => '${row.taskvalue}',
    ));
    print(_seriesPieData.length);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getUserDetails();
  }


   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.white],
            begin: Alignment.topCenter,
            end: Alignment.bottomCenter),
      ),

        child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[

            Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        children:  <Widget>[
                            Container(
                                width : 12,
                                height:12,
                                child: charts.PieChart(
                                  _seriesPieData,
                                  animate: true,
                                  animationDuration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                                  behaviors: [
                                    new charts.DatumLegend(
                                      outsideJustification:
                                      charts.OutsideJustification.endDrawArea,
                                      horizontalFirst: false,
                                      desiredMaxRows: 1,
                                      cellPadding: new EdgeInsets.only(
                                          right: 4.0, bottom: 4.0),
                                      entryTextStyle: charts.TextStyleSpec(
                                          color: charts
                                              .MaterialPalette.purple.shadeDefault,

                                          fontSize: 11),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                  defaultRenderer: new charts.ArcRendererConfig(
                                      arcWidth: 70,
                                      arcRendererDecorators: [
                                        new charts.ArcLabelDecorator(
                                            labelPosition:
                                            charts.ArcLabelPosition.inside)
                                      ]),
                                ),
                              )

                        ],
                      ),


                                Row(
                                    children: [
                                    Column(
                                    children:[

                                       Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Expanded(
                                            child: Text(

                                                "Count free seals:" + "$c",
                                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20)
                                            ),


                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                    )  ,
                                ],
                              ),
                    ],
                  )
                ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
  );
  }
}
```

Screen :
[image]

How I want to share (example):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way (and maybe the only way in Flutter) to do so is by playing with columns, rows and containers.

Based on the example you shared, I would go with :

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'globalvar.dart' as global;

import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;

void main() => runApp(AppS());

class Task {
  String task;
  int taskvalue;
  Color colors;
  Task({this.task, this.taskvalue, this.colors});
}

class AppS extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: Home());
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  List<dynamic> data = [];
  Map<String, dynamic> statsIndia;
  List<charts.Series<Task, String>> _seriesPieData;
  int a, b, c;

  Future<Null> getUserDetails() async {
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.badCertificateCallback =
        ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true);

    final String url = global.urlVar + '/PIE' + '?data_area=' + global.dataArea;
    final request =
        await client.getUrl(Uri.parse(url)).timeout(Duration(seconds: 5));

    HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();

    var responseBody = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();

    data = json.decode(responseBody);
    statsIndia = data[0];
    a = statsIndia["unseals"];
    b = statsIndia["seals"];
    c = statsIndia["free_seals"];
    print(a);
    get();
    setState(() {});
  }

  get() {
    var piedata = [
      new Task(task: "Seals", taskvalue: a, colors: Color(0xfffd2525)),
      new Task(task: "Unseals", taskvalue: b, colors: Color(0xffb5e09b))
    ];
    _seriesPieData.add(charts.Series(
      id: "1", //Was missing
      data: piedata,
      domainFn: (Task task, _) => task.task,
      measureFn: (Task task, _) => task.taskvalue,
      colorFn: (Task task, _) => charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(task.colors),
      labelAccessorFn: (Task row, _) => '${row.taskvalue}',
    ));
    print(_seriesPieData.length);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getUserDetails();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var maxWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    var maxHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          //The background container
          Container(
            width: maxWidth,
            height: maxHeight,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                  colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.white],
                  begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                  end: Alignment.bottomCenter),
            ),
          ),
          //The foreground container which will hold all your cards wrapped in a column
          Container(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                //The "Pie Chart" card
                _seriesPieData.length > 0
                ? Container(
                  width: maxWidth - 30, //I deducted the margin
                  height: (maxHeight * 0.3) -
                      30, //I set the pie chart card to 1/3 of the screen, minus the margin
                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 15, 15, 15),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                          20),
                      ),
                  child: charts.PieChart(
                    _seriesPieData,
                    animate: true,
                    animationDuration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                    behaviors: [
                      new charts.DatumLegend(
                        outsideJustification:
                            charts.OutsideJustification.endDrawArea,
                        horizontalFirst: false,
                        desiredMaxRows: 1,
                        cellPadding:
                            new EdgeInsets.only(right: 4.0, bottom: 4.0),
                        entryTextStyle: charts.TextStyleSpec(
                            color: charts.MaterialPalette.purple.shadeDefault,
                            fontSize: 11),
                      ),
                    ],
                    defaultRenderer: new charts.ArcRendererConfig(
                        arcWidth: 70,
                        arcRendererDecorators: [
                          new charts.ArcLabelDecorator(
                              labelPosition: charts.ArcLabelPosition.inside)
                        ]),
                  ),
                )
                :Container(),
                //The "Count free seals" card
                Container(
                  width: maxWidth - 30, //I deducted the margin
                  height: (maxHeight * 0.7) -
                      30, //I set the user data card to 2/3 of the screen, minus the margin
                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 15, 15, 15),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                          20),
                      ),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: Text("Count free seals:" + "$c",
                            style:
                                TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20)),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The result looks like this :

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks for the help, but when I did following this example I had a lot of mistakes, but my goal is to divide the screen into zones (rectangular cards in the background)

Comment: To fit even more your exemple (grey background and white cards infront) you can use a [Stack Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) encompassing a Column/Row tree as I gave you in my example. Then in each Column/Row, add a white container with BorderRadius parameter to give you the rounded angles. Check the [layouts in Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout) page for more details. :)

Comment: Also, the code I gave you was a canvas to help you structuring your layout. You should adapt it with your code blocks to avoid errors.

Comment: I changed my code (in question) you can see if I understood you correctly, but the result on the screen almost did not change (

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you could help reduce the chart widget to take up less space on my screen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232580/discussion-between-andrii-havrylyak-and-cyril-bvt).

Comment: I replaced as you said, but nothing has changed, I know I'm asking stupid questions, but I just have little experience with it. I specified the changes in the code, in and you can pervert?

Comment: hello, will you have time today to look at my code)?

Comment: Hey Andrii, I updated my answer with the corrected code! Works as you wanted! :)

Comment: Cyril Bvt can I still count on your help?)

Comment: Hi, I don't want to bother you, but I can still count on your help ??